# nginx append date stamp to old logs

Tags: logging, nginx

I wonder how I might achieve naming old nginx logs (both access and error logs). Currently my server adds numbers to these which is default behaviour I guess (looks like this: `access.log.1`).

Can I change the format of the filename somehow so it contains the date stamp for that particular date? Something like `access-26-11-2019.log`?

I haven't set up any log rotation and just launched `nginx` as it is. Not sure if this is done automatically for each day.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have logrotate installed.
Have a look in /etc/logrotate.d/ if there is a file for nginx.

You can add "dateext" to the options to automatically append the date when rotating.

The format can apparently be adjusted with "dateformat" ([man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)), but I recommend to stick with the default since sorting by filename will still be chronologically.

Comment: OK so I enabled logrotate and set up dateformat. However peculiar thing is happening. I have set the log rotation to `daily` which indeed creates rotated log file and appends the timestamp.
The problem is that wrong timestamp is being added to filename. For example logs from Nov 27th are stamped with `2019-11-28`. I guess that the log rotation happens on midnight when it's already the next day?

Comment: This is my logrotate conf file:

```
/var/log/nginx/myapp/*.log {
        daily
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
        missingok
        rotate 14
        notifempty
        create 0640 www-data adm
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi \
        endscript
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
        endscript
}

```

Comment: Logrotate does not know the files content, so it apends the date at the time of rotating.

Comment: Yes I know it's probably not aware of the contents of the files. I just wonder why the date is wrong but probably that's what happens. I'll look into docs on logrotate to see if I can set specific time for rotation and perhaps rotate it just a second before midnight.